# RiotException when loading a Model using Jena 2.12.1

Tags: rdf, jena, dbpedia

I've created this simple class named *RDFReader* for loading a model from a URI from DBpedia:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class RDFReader {
    public static Model readFromURL(String URL){
      try{
         return (new FileManager()).loadModel(URL);
      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;  
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      RDFReader.readFromURL("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pacific_Rim_(film)");
    }   
}
```

I've used *Jena* v2.12.1 as shown in the following snippet of my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

By running this code with *Jena* v2.12.1 I've got the next exception:

```java
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 21, col: 17] Unknown char: –(8211;0x2013)
at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:163)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:106)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:249)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:191)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:44)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:182)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:906)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:687)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:210)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:183)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:121)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:112)
at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:77)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:253)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.readModelWorker(FileManager.java:377)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:308)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:260)
at edu.polito.rdf.utils.RDFReader.readFromURL(RDFReader.java:12)
at edu.polito.rdf.utils.RDFReader.main(RDFReader.java:20)
```

However using *Jena* v2.11.0 the code runs without any problem. So I would like to know:

1. Why does the 2.12.1 version of *Jena* produce this error?
2. Is it possible to solve this problem to use the 2.12.1 version of *Jena* instead of the 2.11.0?.

By the way, I'm using *eclipse Luna 4.4.1* and java version "1.8.0_11".

Comment: Please show the line from the data. It looks like 0x2013 is used in a prefix name, which is illegal in Turtle/RDF 1.1

From jena development master, there is a slightly better error message:  Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: –(8211;0x2013)

Comment: According to the documentation of Jena the method loadModel(String URL) from class com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager load a model from a file (in my case DBpedia) using as default the syntax RDF/XML. In my example I've got the RDF http://dbpedia.org/data/Pacific_Rim_(film).rdf

Comment: Your has : "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pacific_Rim_(film)" -- no ".rdf." so Jena applies content negotiation and lists Turtle before RDF/XML.

Comment: Better to use RDFDataMgr.loadModel anyway (it all comes done to the same machinery).

Comment: @AndyS I've tried with RDFDataMgr.loadMode and got the same Exception.

Comment: Yes - you will.  Its just a different way to the same parser with content negotiation.  The key point is that there was a bug in RIOT that was fixed in 2.12.1 and the parser is now right, whereas previously it was too lenient.  0x2013 (An En-dash, not the hyphen-minus 0x002D codepoint) is not legal at that point and the Turtle from dbpedia is wrong.  Ask DBpedia for N-triples or RDF/XML.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS, now I understand. It works perfectly, I will add the final answer so other with similar problems could understand also and use a similar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying to access to the resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pacific_Rim_(film) which contains a character 0x2013 (Em-dash) that is not legal at that point in Turtle.

These are the answers for both questions:

1. I was using Jena 2.12.1 which applies content negotiation and lists Turtle before RDF/XML so it found that the resource in DBpedia (with Turtle) was wrong (as explained before).  With version 2.11.0 it run without problems because that version had a bug that allowed the parser to be lenient. This bug was then fixed in version 2.12.1, so reading a resource with an illegal character launches the RiotException.
2. The solution was simply to ask DBpedia for the RDF/XML (alternatively N-triples) of the resource which can be accessed through http://dbpedia.org/data/Pacific_Rim_(film).rdf.  The final code to get the RDF/XML from DBpedia is:

*Note: As suggested by @AndyS I’ve used the `RDFDataMgr.loadModel(String URI)`*:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class RDFReader {
   public static Model readFromURL(String URL){
        return RDFDataMgr.loadModel(URL);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model =      RDFReader.readFromURL("http://dbpedia.org/data/Pacific_Rim_(film).rdf");
     }
}
```