# RiotException in execConstruc() method - QueryExecution class - using Jena 2.13

Tags: rdf, jena, dbpedia

When I use the execConstruc() method, it throw RioException after read many RDFs. During this execution, it find some returned triple with incompatible character.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 888, col: 17] Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: –(8211;0x2013)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:163)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:106)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:47)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:185)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:906)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:257)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:231)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:221)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execModel(QueryEngineHTTP.java:432)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execConstruct(QueryEngineHTTP.java:387)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execConstruct(QueryEngineHTTP.java:382)
    at testes.TestReadSparql2.main(TestReadSparql2.java:28)
```

I simplifyed the code to show us only the part related to the problem.

```
package testes;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
public class TestReadSparql2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String queryStr = 
                "CONSTRUCT {"+
                "   ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education> . }"+
                "WHERE {"+
                "   ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education>"+
                "}"
                // + "LIMIT 800"   // adding this line, it is work!!
                ;

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);
        QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",  query);

        // ERROR AT NEXT LINE - in execConstruct(): "org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException ... Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: –(8211;0x2013)"
        Model model = queryExecution.execConstruct();

        StmtIterator stmtIterator = model.listStatements();
        while (stmtIterator.hasNext()) {
            Statement statement = stmtIterator.nextStatement();  
            System.out.println(statement.getSubject().toString() + " -> " + 
                               statement.getPredicate().toString() + " -> " + 
                               statement.getObject().toString());
        }
        queryExecution.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the same code configured to show the first 800 triples (for example) it is ok!  For this, just add the next line in the query (it is indicated as comment in the above code):

```
 + "LIMIT 800" '
```

In this case, the first triples are shown correctly:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/BBNM -> http://dbpedia.org/property/industry -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education
    http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Liberator_Magazine -> http://dbpedia.org/property/category -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education
    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fisdap -> http://dbpedia.org/property/data -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education
    http://dbpedia.org/resource/WUVS-LP -> http://dbpedia.org/property/format -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education
    http://dbpedia.org/resource/5_and_Up -> http://dbpedia.org/property/format -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education
```

I have searched a lot in the internet and I have found only 1 person with similar problem: [RiotException when loading a Model using Jena 2.12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495240/riotexception-when-loading-a-model-using-jena-2-12-1) 
But, unfortunately, it did not help me.

By the way, I'm using eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and java version 1.8.0_40

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your analysis - http://dbpedia.org/sparql returns a triple with an incompatible character.

```
[line: 888, col: 17] Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: –(8211;0x2013)
```

That means that on line 888 of the response, there is a 0x2013 (an en-dash character) and looks like its being used as a minus (0x002D).  They can look the same but they aren't. 0x2013 is illegal in a Turtle prefix name.

Line 888 is:

```
dbpedia:Novitas_–_ROYAL dbpedia-owl:academicDiscipline  dbpedia:Education .
                ^ wrong
```

Worse - the URI in the data is actually http://dbpedia.org/resource/Novitas_%E2%80%93_ROYAL (I used RDF/XML output to find it). The %E2%80%93 should not have converted in the Turtle. (%E2%80%93 is percent-encoded UTF-8 0x2013)

The N-triples is also wrong; the JSON-LD is right.

So you should be able to can use one of those formats instead (cast the QueryExecution to QueryEngineHTTP and call setModelContentType before using execConstruct).

Let DBpedia know the Turtle output is bad.

Unrelated: you can write your query as:

```
CONSTRUCT WHERE { ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Education> . }
```

Comment: Resolved. I just used QueryEngineHTTP insted of QueryExecution and I have configured it with  setModelContentType(WebContent.contentTypeJSONLD).  Thank you a lot @AndyS for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

As stated this is caused by an incompatible character. I include a full code snippet below as a reference. `RDF/XML`is used as the requested mime type, and the model can then be serialized as `TTL`:

```java
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(targetEndpoint, query);
QueryEngineHTTP qeHttp = (QueryEngineHTTP) qe;
qeHttp.setModelContentType("application/rdf+xml");
// Serialize it
Model m = qe.execConstruct();
m.write(System.out, "TTL");
```